# Casting an Object type to Page from NavigationService.Content

Tags: c#, wpf

I am new to C# and WPF and have a problem. I have an application with the main window and a couple of pages.

I need to set a label in the main window with the page.title property. I know i could create an event in each page On_loaded(or similar), but what I have tried is in the main window did this:

```
  void NavigationService_Navigated(object sender, NavigationEventArgs e)
  {
  PageTitleLabel.Content = this.getPageTitle((Page)MainFrame.NavigationService.Content);
  }

  private String getPageTitle(Page page) {

  return String.Copy(page.Title);

  }
```

Unfortunately this doesn't update the label.
I think it is a problem with getting the orignal object out of the object or the Event never starts, Or the label needs to be redraw somehow.

Kind Regards

Comment: I'm confused (don't panic - I usually exist in that state) - are you asking about setting a label value or launching Skype?

Comment: Sorry this has a title of older question which i figured out, it was easy, poeple were messing with all these Skype and Lync apis and i just did a hyperlink "Call: number" which does exacly that:) I am asking for changing the content in code behind, but I want to extract the property of the page object but unfortunately MainFrame.NavigationService.Content returns object:(